# What does BLOCKED state mean for Quartz trigger

Tags: quartz-scheduler

For some Quartz job, it misfired; and after checked the trigger status in database, it shows `BLOCKED`. What does this `BLOCKED` mean specifically?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

WAITING = the normal state of a trigger, waiting for its fire time to arrive and be acquired for firing by a scheduler.

PAUSED = means that one of the scheduler.pauseXXX() methods was used. The trigger is not eligible for being fired until it is resumed.

ACQUIRED = a scheduler node has identified this trigger as the next trigger it will fire - may still be waiting for its fire time to arrive. After it fires the trigger will be updated (per its repeat settings, if any) and placed back into the WAITING state (or be deleted if it does not repeat again).

BLOCKED = the trigger is prevented from being fired because it relates to a StatefulJob that is already executing. When the statefuljob completes its execution, all triggers relating to that job will return to the WAITING state.

In other words, When a state is BLOCKED, another trigger (or an instance of this trigger) is already executing for the trigger's stateful job, so this trigger is blocked until the other trigger is finished.

Link to documentation could be useful for your future reference.http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/quartz/Trigger.html

Comment: My trigger has been blocked for 5 days. What do I do to fix it?

Comment: Follow up: In my case, if I just stop the service and update the trigger state to "waiting", then restart service, it will continue working. Not sure if that has any terrible side effects though

Comment: @JoePhillips : I think, when you stop the service that essentially kills all active threads and this would free up connections for your waiting thread and possibly why it works after. Would be good to check the active jobs when you stop the service and verify all the actions that the job is intended to perform are completed. If yes, then look at why the job wouldn't release the thread even after it has completed all the operations.

Comment: "Perhaps some search would help before posting a question here?", 6 years later, this is now the first result in Google...

Comment: Your link is broken.