# Quartz 1.6 job status in blocked

Tags: java, cron, jobs, quartz

We have quartz job in our application and its running in every minute. The job is running for few minutes later the job is moved to blocked state and its not started again, We are using quartz 1.6 jar.

Comment: Regarding the state of the trigger you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736881/what-does-blocked-state-mean-for-quartz-trigger). How many threads are reserved for the quartz scheduler,what is the misfire configuration setting .Could you post your quartz scheduler settings.